# SignalR-client sends a large number of requests in a short period of time

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

We use SignalR in ASP.NET application with js+HTML5 web client. We also use MS SQL Server 2008 as a [backplane](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server) for SignalR because of the need to support a cluster configuration.

Recently we ran into problems on the customer's server. Our application didn't respond for request about an hour with this message in error log:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

We have analyzed the IIS logs for the previous period and found the following:

For 30 minutes, the server received 724,103 requests from the same IP-address and with the same connectionToken:

```
2015-12-28 08:18:57 10.162.4.141 POST /signalr/poll transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=GSUZGb0jOI3xAoMLdfDwCbjxekvIShkOXOSpg9CjpNZ1Oi4FtMEF%2BiTgf4R1lXgULv6XuQO%2F4S3wQYcfl8tj5yI0b%2Bg2%2B1KSwv0d%2FZifAbEzxa4rp28S4EHZJiMAH7A5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22messenger%22%7D%5D&orgid=1 80 - 10.162.64.142 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:43.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/43.0 (page url - skipped) 200 0 0 15
```

Three weeks ago there was a similar case. We found 70,000 requests in the IIS logs with the same connectionToken for a slightly shorter period of time.

We do not know whether it is caused by SignalR, network, client's browser, or something else.
What might be the cause of these incidents? How can this be avoided?

**UPD1:**
Our application is running in intranet. We have found these two users and we asked the customer to check their computers, but nothing suspicious was discovered. We can not completely exclude the possibility of an attack, but requests come from the computers of ordinary employees.

**UPD2:**
We need to find the reason for this behavior of the client.
Or, maybe, is there a way to limit amount of requests per second per user on the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases connection pooling problems are related to "DB connection leaks." Connections are cheap but they do run-out.

You need to make sure you are closing your SQL connection.

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
try
{
     connection.Open();
     someCall (connection);
}
finally
{
     connection.Close();                
}
```

OR

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     connection.Open();
     someCall(connection);
}
```

Your error message occurs when too many connections are not closed.

The bug could be in the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer package that you are using or it could be in your code.

Also, if you use SqlDataReader or a OleDbDataReader in your code, close them. Put in the effort to close your data reader objects explicitly when you use them.

If you want to really scale, I suggest trying Reddis to scale out - it is super fast and free:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis

Comment: Thanks for you response! We will look at Reddis. Perhaps we should move the SignalR's backplane in a separate database.
But in everyday life we have no problems with SignalR for six months. I'm trying to find a reason of these accidents.

Comment: I can't really say that problem is actually in db connection leaks. We haven't unclosed connections in our code and I can't say anything about SignalR package.
But 400 requests per second per user - this is clearly not normal anyway. So I'll leave the question open yet as we need to find the reason for this behavior of the client.

Comment: @Digger2000 If you found the reason for this error would you please share some information? I am also not convinced that it is open DB connections for us. The stack trace never makes it that far.

Comment: @Thomas927 I'm afraid I didn't manage to find the reason.
This happened several more times with other instances of the system and lasted from 6 to 12 hours.
As a result, we rewrote our real-time subsystem with Node.js + primus.